# utf8mb4 y utf8 en MySQL, ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: mysql

Desde la última actualización de PHPMyAdmin veo que ahora el juego de caracteres que trae por defecto es `utf8mb4`.

Me gustaría saber cuál es la diferencia entre `utf8mb4` y `utf8` y si se conoce algún motivo específico por el que existe esta variante, si podemos llamarla así, de utf8.

También, si decido cambiar el conjunto de caracteres de mis tablas y columnas a `utf8mb4` quisiera saber si podría tener algún problema.

Comment: Pues por lo poco que leí creo que la diferencia radica en que `utf8` utiliza tres bytes por caracter y solo contiene caracteres `BMP` mientras que `utf8mb4` acepta un máximo de cuatro caracteres dandole soporte a caracteres suplementarios. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

Comment: No he entendido el voto negativo a tu pregunta. +1

Comment: @cnbandicoot Resulta que hay dos o tres a los que no les caigo bien y en cuanto pregunto o respondo se me echan encima, votando negativo sin decir por que votan negativo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

buen día, como lo menciona la documentación, desde la versión MySQL 5.5.3 se agrega esta "variante" de utf.
¿Ahora cual es la diferencia?

UTF-8
[La codificación UTF-8](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8) puede representar cada símbolo en el conjunto de caracteres Unicode, que va de U + 000.000 a U + 10FFFF. Eso es 1,114,112 símbolos posibles. (No todos estos puntos de código Unicode se han asignado caracteres todavía, pero eso no impide que UTF-8 de la posibilidad de codificarlos.)

Muchas de las veces hemos usado de MySQL utf8charset para bases de datos, tablas y columnas, suponiendo que asigna a la codificación UTF-8 descrito anteriormente. Mediante el uso utf8, asumiendo que se puede almacenar casi cualquier símbolo.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;


 SET NAMES utf8;
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
UPDATE ForgeRock SET description = 'foobar' WHERE id = 3;
```

Ahora ver warings:

```
SHOW WARNINGS\G


+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                      |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x8C\x86' for column 'description' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Resulta de MySQL utf8charset sólo parcialmente implementa adecuada codificación UTF-8. Los símbolos que constan de uno a tres bytes UTF-8-codificada; símbolos codificados que ocupan cuatro bytes no son compatibles.

Esto no sólo afecta el carácter, pero los símbolos más importantes como U + 01F4A9  ( ) también. En total, de los 1,048,575 posibles puntos de código no se puede utilizar. De hecho, de MySQL utf8 sólo se le permite almacenar un 5,88% ( (0x00FFFF + 1) / (0x10FFFF + 1)) de todos los posibles puntos de código Unicode. Proper UTF-8 puede codificar 100% de todos los puntos de código Unicode.

Ahora si en tus tablas o bd deseas cambiar la codificación pues utf8mb4 es totalmente compatible con utf8, solo antes de moverle algo, crea un respaldo de tu información.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Aunque hay partes del contenido que no se entienden muy bien.  Podría considerarla como aceptada si mejorases ese pequeño defecto.

Answer (score 5):

Tal y como comenta la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> `utf8` usa un máximo de tres bytes por carácter y contiene solo
>   carácteres BMP. Por el contraro, `utf8mb4` usa un máximo de 4 bytes
>   por carácter, soportando carácteres suplementarios.
>
> **Consejo**: Para guardar espacio con `utf8mb4` usa **`VARCHAR`** en vez
>   de **`CHAR`**.

Answer (score 3):

**En resumen:**

1. En MySQL **utf8** aunque aparenta no es realmente UTF-8 (este falso aparente te haría creer erróneamente que puedes guardar cualquier caracter, emoji o símbolo compatible con el estándar UTF-8).
2. **utf8mb4** es realmente UTF-8 por lo que cualquier caracter que se puede expresar usando el estándar UTF-8 podría expresarse correctamente dentro de la base de datos.

**Detalle:**

La diferencia principal entre "utf8" y "utf8mb4" radica en la capacidad para almacenar los caracteres de 4 bytes utilizados por algunos símbolos y emoji en Unicode. Si se usa el conjunto de caracteres "utf8" en MySQL, es posible que ocurran errores al intentar almacenar o recuperar esos caracteres de 4 bytes, lo que puede resultar en la pérdida de datos o en la sustitución de esos caracteres con valores incorrectos.

Por lo tanto, al utilizar "utf8mb4" en lugar de "utf8", se garantiza que todos los caracteres Unicode, incluidos los emoji, se almacenen y se manipulen correctamente en una base de datos MySQL. Esto es especialmente importante si planeas almacenar o procesar texto que contenga caracteres de 4 bytes, como los emoji.