# ¿Qué cotejamiento UTF8 usar en MySql según el idioma?

Tags: mysql

Habitualmente **uso cotejamiento `utf8_general_ci` en bases de datos MySql para guardar datos en castellano e inglés**. En algún momento me recomendaron este cotejamiento, nunca he sabido si era mejor por ejemplo que `utf8_spanish_ci`. Ahora también estoy viendo que se incluyen cotejamientos `utf8mb4*`, hay un [hilo abierto sobre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65950).

Estoy viendo que ***laravel 5.7*** viene al instalar con `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` en el fichero de configuración ***"config/database.php"***. Como la configuración inicial es para crear aplicaciones en inglés se me plantea la duda actual y si conviene cambiar este cotejamiento y a cual según el lenguaje o los lenguajes en los que vamos a desarrollar.

Comment: el cotejamiento `utf8mb4` entre otras cosas se da para tener capacidad de almacenar caracteres como los `emojis` que los anteriores sistemas de cotejamiento no permitían (o mas que no permitir tenían implementado a medias), pues data cuyos elementos que al estar códificados  son de 4 o mas bytes no son compatibles, por eso mi ejemplo de los emojis

Comment: `utf8mb4` es el utf8 real ( utf 8 multibyte 4 bytes) en el caso de mysql el `utf8` implementado originalmente es un subset de sólo 3 bytes. si sólo manejas inglés y español vas a encontrar la limitación en emojis, si trabajas con otros lenguajes que realmente usan los 4 bytes `utf8mb4` es la que va. Hoy por hoy te conviene mas el mb4 para soportar caracteres extendidos

Comment: Mira ese link https://drupal.ed.team/blog/en-mysql-nunca-uses-utf8-usa-utf8mb4