# Cual es la funcion que cumplen los cotejamiento utf8mb4_general_ci o utf8_general_ci o cp852_bin

Tags: mysql

No se si esta bien preguntar esto, pero es un tema que me quedo pendiente. Generalmente cuando creo una base de datos eligo el cotejamiento `utf8_general_ci` y la verdad lo hago porque una vez me lo dijeron y nunca me dijeron porque.

Base de datos local

```
Base de datos | Cotejamiento      | Accion
crm           | utf8mb4_general_ci | Seleccionar privilegios
pruebas       | utf8_general_ci    | Seleccionar privilegios
```

Los cotejamientos influyen a la hora de crear un sistema o una app o un simple listado de datos?

> NOTA: LA PREGUNTA DICE CUAL ES LA FUNCION QUE CUMPLE LOS COTEJAMIENTOS Y NO CUAL ES LA DIFERENCIA. EN NINGUN MOMENTO PREGUNTO CUAL ES LA DIFERENCIA.
>   EL LO MISMO USAR utf8mb4_general_ci o utf8_general_ci o cp852_bin?,
>   PORQUE NO ES LO MISMO? PORQUE MYSQL LISTA MAS DE 100 COTEJAMIENTOS?

NO ENTIENDO PORQUE QUIEREN CERRAR LA PREGUNTA, SI LAS RESPUESTAS DICEN "CUAL ES LA DIFERENCIA" Y YO PREGUNTO "QUE FUNCION CUMPLE'.

Gracias!

Comment: Sigo la pregunta porque es interesante.

Comment: Si, puede ser, no me quedo bien en claro, pero voy a seguir leyendo dentro de la pregunta que has enviado. Gracias

Comment: @Aprendiz lei la pregunta y no dice cual es funcion. En el caso que yo quiera hacer un sitio en chino, el cotejamiento influye o no? Y no creo que la respuesta sea: "y si queres hacer una pagina en chino usa el cotejamiento tal".

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera siempre existe la opción de contestar a esta pregunta, pero depende si el OP lo considera o no aún necesario

Comment: Las diferencias principales son cómo los datos se ordenan y cómo se comparan. Los enlaces están en inglés pero te pueden dar una idea: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php

Comment: Esta pregunta esta duplicada [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65950/utf8mb4-y-utf8-en-mysql-cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia)

Comment: @KenThompson yo no pregunto cual es la direfencia, yo pregunte que funcion cumple y si influye en algo utilizar los que ya uso o usar `cp852_bin`. Por algo mysql tiene una lista con muchos cotejamientos. Entonces, estas porque si? Creo que no estan leyendo bien la pregunta.

Comment: Ok, si, no la ley bien, bueno te puedo decir que a groso modo los cotejamientos son sets de datos que se usan según los idiomas locales, en Ingles por ejemplo UTF8 no se usan acentos, en cambio en español si, hay otros idiomas que poseen sus propio alfabeto como el Ruso y ahí se usa otro cotejameinto.

Comment: Esta pregunta es **demasiado amplia**. Si preguntas eso, es porque no sabes lo que es un [**sistema de codificación de caracteres**.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres). A modo muy breve, la `ñ` tiene números distintos asociados según la codificación escogida. Si los números son distintos ... ¿ como hacemos la comparación ?